# Use reduce function to compare symbol in the two string

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

I try to compare two strings in array on equal symbols or char,this code works, but how to implement it in ES6 with reduce method, if I have more than two strings an array. I need to return true if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array. But how to create the more flexible function if I have more than 2 elments in the array.

```
function mutation(arr) {
      var arr2 = arr.map(item => item.toLowerCase().split(''));
      for (i=0;i<arr2[1].length;i++) {
        if (arr2[0].indexOf(arr2[1][i]) < 0)
          return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Comment: Why are you taking an array and then doing `arr2` and refering it by index? Why doesn't the function just take `first` and `second`?

Comment: Your code is just `function mutation(first, second) {
  first = first.toLowerCase();
  second = second.toLowerCase();
  return Array.from(second).every(c => first.includes(c));
}`.

Comment: Or with `reduce` if you must... `function mutation(first, second) {
  first = first.toLowerCase();
  second = second.toLowerCase();
  return Array.from(second).reduce((p, c) => p && first.includes(c), true);
}`

Comment: I need to return true if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array. But how to create the more flexible function if I have more than 2 elments in the array.

Comment: What's wrong in just doing `arr[0] === arr[1]`?

Comment: Or you don't care about the order? so `['hello', 'eeeeelllllooooooh']` returns true?

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro well, for one you'd write the version I wrote above, afterwards, you'd call it for every one of the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

@Palaniichuk I thought your original algorithm was pretty solid.  To handle your request I was able to create a solution that uses reduce.

I do have one question for you.  Should the array increase in size, how would the strings be evaluated?

The reason I ask is because using a helper function like this might help you scale this algorithm.  Of course it all depends on how the input changes.  How the inputs are evaluated.

```
function makeStr(string) {
  const reducer = string.split('').reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b] = a[b] + 1 || 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(reducer).sort().join('');
}

function secondMutation(arr) {
  const array = [...arr].map(makeStr);
    return array[0].includes(array[1]);
};

console.log(secondMutation(["hello", "hell"]));
```